# error in cancel button function

Tags: jquery

I am recieving an error below in my error console which doesn't show in the view source where the problem is:

```
typeError: $(...).text(...).html is not a function
```

But by trying to figure out where the error is coming from the error I believe is in the piece of code below as it appears after I click the cancel button:

```
function htmlEncode(value) { return $('<div/>').text(value).html(); }
```

I can't find in google what this problem is but does anyone see an error in my jquery code? The error in the code may cause the error in the console if there is an error.

FULL CODE:

Below is the html encode:

```
function htmlEncode(value) { return $('<div/>').text(value).html(); }
```

Function for starting the upload:

```
    function startImageUpload(imageuploadform){

      $(imageuploadform).find('.imagef1_upload_process').css('visibility','visible');
      $(imageuploadform).find('.imagef1_cancel').css('visibility','visible');
      $(imageuploadform).find('.imagef1_upload_form').css('visibility','hidden');
      $(imageuploadform).find('.imagemsg').css('visibility','hidden');
      sourceImageForm = imageuploadform;

            $(".sbtnimage").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $(".sbtnvideo").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $(".sbtnaudio").attr("disabled", "disabled");

            $(imageuploadform).find(".imageCancel").on("click", function(event) {
                      $('.upload_target_image').get(0).contentwindow;
                      stopImageUpload(2);

          $("iframe[name='upload_target_image']").on("load",function() {
          stopImageUpload(1);
        }).attr("src", "cancelimage.php");

    }); 
          return true;
    }

          var imagecounter = 0;
```

Function that stops the upload:

```
    function stopImageUpload(success, imagefilename){

          var result = '';
          imagecounter++;

          if (success == 1){
             result = '<span class="imagemsg'+imagecounter+'">The file was uploaded successfully</span>';      
             $('.listImage').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).append('<div>' + htmlEncode(imagefilename) + '<button type="button" class="deletefileimage" image_file_name="' + imagefilename + '">Remove</button><br/><hr/></div>'); 
          }
          else if (success == 2){
              result = '<span class="imagemsg'+imagecounter+'"> The file upload was cancelled</span>';
          }
          else {
             result = '<span class="imagemsg'+imagecounter+'">There was an error during file upload</span>';
          }

          $(sourceImageForm).find('.imagef1_upload_process').css('visibility','hidden');
          $(sourceImageForm).find('.imagef1_cancel').css('visibility','hidden');
          $(sourceImageForm).find('.imagemsg').html(result);
          $(sourceImageForm).find('.imagemsg').css('visibility','visible'); 
          $(sourceImageForm).find(".fileImage").replaceWith("<input type='file' class='fileImage' name='fileImage' />");
          $(sourceImageForm).find('.imagef1_upload_form').css('visibility','visible');

          $(".sbtnimage").removeAttr("disabled");
          $(".sbtnvideo").removeAttr("disabled");
          $(".sbtnaudio").removeAttr("disabled");

            $(".imageClear").on("click", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).parents("form:first").find(".fileImage").replaceWith("<input type='file' class='fileImage' name='fileImage' />");

        });

      var _imagecounter = imagecounter;

    $('.listImage').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).find(".deletefileimage").on("click", function(event) {
        var image_file_name = $(this).attr('image_file_name');

        jQuery.ajax("deleteimage.php?imagefilename=" + image_file_name)
            .done(function(data) {

            $(".imagemsg" + _imagecounter).html(data);
        });

        $(this).parent().remove();
    });

          return true;   
    }
```

ImageclickHandler() function:

```
  function imageClickHandler(imageuploadform){ 
  if(imageValidation(imageuploadform)){ 
      window.lastUploadImageIndex = $('.imageuploadform').index(imageuploadform); 
      return startImageUpload(imageuploadform); 
  } 
  return false;
}
```

UPDATE:

Below is php code where it uploads the file:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);


session_start();


if ($_FILES['fileImage']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $result = 0;


    if (getimagesize($_FILES['fileImage']['tmp_name'])) {
        if ((($_FILES["fileImage"]["type"] == "image/gif") || ($_FILES["fileImage"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["fileImage"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg") || ($_FILES["fileImage"]["type"] == "image/jpg")) && ($_FILES['fileImage']['size'] > 0)) {
            if (is_file("ImageFiles/" . $_FILES['fileImage']['name'])) {
                $parts = explode(".", $_FILES['fileImage']['name']);
                $ext   = array_pop($parts);
                $base  = implode(".", $parts);
                $n     = 2;

                while (is_file("ImageFiles/" . $base . "_" . $n . "." . $ext))
                    $n++;
                $_FILES['fileImage']['name'] = $base . "_" . $n . "." . $ext;

                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileImage"]["tmp_name"], "ImageFiles/" . $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"]);
                $result = 1;


            }

            else {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileImage"]["tmp_name"], "ImageFiles/" . $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"]);
                $result = 1;
            }

        }

    }
} else {
    echo "Upload was not successful";
}

?> 

  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">window.top.stopImageUpload(<?php
echo $result;
?>, '<?php
echo $_FILES['fileImage']['name'];
?>');</script> 



</body> 
</html>
```

UPDATE 2:

Current code of the iframe load:

```
 $(imageuploadform).find(".imageCancel").on("click", function(event) {
                  $('.upload_target_image').get(0).contentwindow;
                  stopImageUpload(2);

      $("iframe[name='upload_target_image']").on("load",function() {
      stopImageUpload(1);
    }).attr("src", "cancelimage.php");
```

Original code of the iframe load:

```
$(imageuploadform).find(".imageCancel").on("click", function(event) {
                  $('.upload_target_image').get(0).contentwindow;

      $("iframe[name='upload_target_image']").on("load",function() {
      stopImageUpload(2);
    }).attr("src", "cancelimage.php");
```

What happended with the orignal code was that when a file uploaded succesfully, what happended was that a split second it displayed the success == 1 message but then straight away it displayed the cancel message which is success -- 2.

This was obviously incorrect so to try to fix it, I tried the current code solution so that what I thought would happen is that if cancelled, display the success == 2 message, if file was successful, it displays the success == 1 message and that message did not change. But as worked out thanks to Barman that is causing the error I am having

Comment: What is the definition of `imageuploadform`?

Comment: The code you posted is not causing this error, since it doesn't have `.text()` or `.html()` anywhere in it.

Comment: @PraveenKumar let me post full code

Comment: @Barmar full code posted btw

Comment: There's no `.text()` in that code, either.

Comment: Enable "pause on exceptions" in the Javascript debugger, so you can find the exact line that's causing the error.

Comment: @Barmar Using firebug the line the error is happening is here: `function htmlEncode(value) { return $('<div/>').text(value).html(); }` I updated question

Comment: I tried defining your `htmlEncode()` function and it works fine for me.

Comment: @user1930247 Dude, it works. Your method is right. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `stopImageUpload()` expects 2 arguments, but you're only supplying 1 argument. The second argument is supposed to be the filename.  Then you call `htmlEncode(imagefilename)` with this undefined filename argument, which calls `$('<div/>').text(undefined).html()`.  `$('<div/>').text(undefined)` is treated by jQuery as if it were `$('<div/>').text()`, so it returns the string `""`. Then it tries to call `"".html()`, which is not valid.

The fix is to pass the filename argument to the function. But I'm not sure where you can get the filename from, so I think you may just have to remove the code that tries to put the filename into the DIV.

Comment: I have included an additional code where it displays a seperate php script where it does the file uploading server side, is this what you need to see in order to retrieve filename? Also are you saying remove this line        `$('.listImage').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).append('<div>' + htmlEncode(imagefilename) + '<button type="button" class="deletefileimage" image_file_name="' + imagefilename + '">Remove</button><br/><hr/></div>'); `? Because I really need that line. I prefer the pass the filename argument to the function method

Comment: I've looked closer. It works OK in the successful case, because `imageupload.php` returns Javascript code that calls `stopImageUpload()` with the filename of the image it just received. `stopImageUpload()` only tries to display the filename when `success == 1`. The problem is that the cancel click handler calls it first with `success == 2`, which is OK, but then in the iframe `load` handler it calls it again with `success == 1`. I'm not sure why you need that second call, since there's no successful upload to report.

Comment: I included an update 2 in my question which provides an explanation to your comment, maybe that change I did in that iframe load is causing the whole problem. Do you know what it should be fixed to. I beleive if that is fixed then the HtmlEncode will not have an error and thus this will be all solved

Answer (score 0):

`.text()` returns a **string**, it won't have a method `.html()`.

And the error is not from your posted piece code, maybe in `stopImageUpload`.

Comment: `.text()` returns a string, but `.text(something)` is chainable and returns the element being operated on.

Comment: @Barmar Yep, that's true, but the code is odd, `.text(something).html(something_another)` makes non sense.

Comment: Good point. It's valid semantically, but logically erroneous.

Comment: @xdazz Can you see my update where I have included full code to see if you know where problem could be?

Comment: The error is on this line: `function htmlEncode(value) { return $('<div/>').text(value).html(); }`

Answer (score 0):

#### Just replace:

```
return $('<div/>').text(value).html();
```

#### With:

```
return $('<div/>').text(value).end().html();
```

#### Or

```
$('<div/>').text(value);
return value;
```

---

#### Update: The original script works:

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z6VzH/

Comment: Your second version just returns the value unchanged, what's the point of it? I tried your first version in the JS console, it returns `null`.

Comment: Weird... I am still not clear, what the OP wants... Dude, what did you try? Value will be `null` when you just execute the code. Where have you declared the value of `value`?

Comment: `value` is an argument to the function.

Comment: The purpose of this function is to encode something like `>foo` to `&gt;foo` so that it can be included in HTML.

Comment: Works for me, too, as I wrote above. There must be some more stuff the OP isn't showing us that's interfering with it.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Isn't the line in your jsfiddle the same line of code as I already have?

Comment: The code does work, it is just displaying an error in the console but the code is still accepted in all browsers and works, I have shown the whole code, there is no other code really that will mess with this, the only thing missing really is the HTML I have not displayedbut will that have an affect or is it just showing a silly error and I should just ignore it?

Comment: @user1930247 Yes, the original code of yours works. Can you try making a fiddle out of the code so that we can check what is the issue? Make a fiddle. :)

Comment: I won't be able to make fiddle because it requires other php page to access in order for the whole thing to work but I can create a demo application in the browser for you to see, you can then check it in firefox if you have it and see if you get the error as well

Comment: @PraveenKumar Here is the application [app](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/QandATable3.php) I have include all the code which deals with the image file upload. To use app just click on the "Add" button first. When the file upload feature appears, browse for a file and then click on the "Upload" button to upload, but while uploading then click on the "Cancel" button, you will then see the error. I will check to see if the error appears if file is successfully uploaded without being cancelled

Comment: @PraveenKumar Yeah the error also appears if the file is uploaded successfully as well

Comment: @PraveenKumar Please look at barmar answer and comments we posted when you have chance and update to question/ Found the line of code that is creating the error